# Random variable is uniformly distributed on interval $[a, 4]$ and mean of this variable is $3$. Estimate $P(|X| < 3)$. Use Chebyshev’s inequality!

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution

Random variable is uniformly distributed on interval $[a, 4]$ and mean of this variable is $3$. Estimate $P(|X| < 3)$. Use Chebyshev’s inequality!

It is obvious that $a = 2$, as we have a uniform distribution. I have no idea how to solve it using Chebyshev’s inequality. I got stuck here: $$P(|X - 3| < k) \ge 1 - \frac{\sigma^2}{k^2}$$.

Comment: Are you sure that question is worded/translated correctly? It doesn't make much sense, as you've observed.

Comment: What exactly do you find confusing?

Comment: 1. The conditions imply that $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[2, 4]$. Therefore $P(|X| < 3) = 1/2$ without invoking Chebyshev. 2. Why is the absolute value of $X$ taken? There is no chance that $X < 0$. 3. Chebyshev usually gives a probability in terms of the mean and the variance. But the variance is not given.

Comment: 1. Using Chebyshev's inequality is requirement of the problem. I agree that it can be solved like you did. We are asked to estimate the probability using the inequality though. 2. Part of the problem, I have not made it up. 3. Variance is 1/3. Var(X) = (b-a)^2/12 for uniform distribution

Comment: Unless you change 'Find $P(|X|<3)$' to 'estimate $P(|X|<3)$' the question makes no sense.

Comment: "But the variance is not given." Except, of course, implicitly by the fact that the distribution is uniform. But this is a weird application, if so.

Comment: I have just calculated variance. It is 1/3. Therefore, P(|x - 3| < k) >= 1 - 1/(3*k^2). The question is how to estimate P(|X| < 3)

Comment: It's still unclear what you're allowed to use. If all you know is that the mean is $3$ and the variance is $1/3$ (that is, you don't know the actual distribution, the maximum, or anything like that), then Chebyshev can't tell you anything; as you've noted, the denominator is $k^2 = 0$. Since we know the probability is between $0$ and $1$, we don't have an actually infinite probability, but the probability that $X < 3$ still could be anything in the interval $[0, 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have $P(|X|<3)$, and the interval is $[2,4]$, then you hace
$$
P(|X|<3) = P(X<3) = P(X \leq 3) \tag{because of equalty P-ctp}
$$
then, because of X is uniformly distributed on $[2,4]$, the probability is just $P(X\leq3)= \frac{1}{4-2}=\frac{1}{2}$ wich has (for intuition) sense.

In the first equation, notice that X is a random variable positive!